# sha1 encryption with passPhrase ,saltValue,passwordIterations,initVector,keySize

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, sha1

I'm developing java application and I was asked to generate secure code using following information.

```
Value to be encrypted ="test1234";

passPhrase = "testValue"
saltValue  = "testValue"
hashAlgorithm = "SHA1"
passwordIterations = 2
initVector = "testValue"
keySize = 256
```

Could some one kindly let me know what is the approach to generate hash value using SHA1 algorithm based on above mention values.

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you are attempting to do. We cannot guess what is required based on merely the inputs to the process.

Comment: Look for PBKDF2 on this site.

Comment: Note that `initVector` is invalid (no encoding, wrong length, not random - if used with CBC mode encryption) and that you need to define how to encode the plain text ("to be encrypted"), `passPhrase` and `saltValue` into bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague, but I think you probably want to use PBKDF2 to generate the hash. Fortunately, it's pretty simple in Java SE 6+

```
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passsword.toCharArray(), salt, 
   iterations, derivedKeyLength);
SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
```

There's a more in-depth explanation at http://jerryorr.blogspot.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-lots-of-donts.html

Comment: +1 although feeding it a string instead of a character array kind of defeats the purpose, and there is no need to call `getEncoded()` on something that is already a `SecretKey`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on what you wanna do with the SecretKey.